# Diagram making for latex organizational strength

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I want to make such a kind of diagram for my thesis. Can someone help me to make one like this? I am not able to find any template like this anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions of the form "Do this for me" are not perceived very well. For drawing purposes you might have a look at the `tikz` package and see how far you'll get with that

Comment: Probably the smartdiagram package could be useful.

Comment: I am curious whether anyone learns anything useful from this diagram. But I don't have a B.BA, so maybe I am not qualified to gronk the content.

Comment: May this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169105/drawing-arrows-on-a-circle-path-and-a-tangent-arrow-in-tikz helps you...

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [-Reproducing a figure in tikz with text and arrows flowing round in a circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469860/138900)

Comment: I voted to close this but I realised that it is not a duplicate because in this question the text does not follow the arrows as it does in the alleged duplicate...